# Sharing same stdout between 2 processes in win32, c++

Tags: c++, stdout, win32-process

I have 2 processes in my Win32 console application.
1 process - main program
1 process - cli process.

These 2 processes communicate through UDP packets (Sockets).
Cli issues a request for a DUMP on a specific entity in the main program.

I want the dump to be printed on the stdout of the CLI (using printf prints it in the main program stdout).

How can I do it?
I want to pass FILE* or similar.... Pass the output device to dump to.

How can it be done? If possible at all

Thanks
yoav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return the DUMP information to the CLI program and let it print it to stdout !

Comment: This is one option. But I want to pass the stdout? Is it possible?